# Bash shell with problematic outcomes under Linux (C)

Tags: io-redirection, c

Following my [previous post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39335/redirection-from-files-using-operator-in-c), I still have one annoying bug that won't leave .

I wrote a simulator for the `bash` command under Linux.

When I run my code in a single run, with the these commands:

```
ls Debug/ | grep r
ls >> file.jer & ls & ls & ls &
ls >> file.jer
ls > file1.rrr
ls & ls | grep e
ls & ls & ls &
ls Debug/ | grep r
ls Debug/ > k.out
ls Debug/ >> k.out
exit
```

then in the third line `ls >> file.jer` the program writes `ls: cannot access : No such file or directory` . When I run the program and every run I hit the inputs **separately** then the correct output is presented. I've tried to debug this so many times, but couldn't find the problem.

**Specific problem**: when I run the code and hit `ls Debug/ | grep r` , the correct output is presented. Following that, when I hit `ls >> file.jer & ls & ls & ls &` , also here the code works great. But when I hit `ls >> file.jer` , then something very wrong is happening, and I can't seem to find its source , where again the output for the `3rd` command is 
**No such file or directory** , but clearly it's wrong, since when I run it in a single run, the file `file.jer` is appended with the contents of the current path.

I have a `main`, and two `.h` files with their two `.c` files.

Comment: This is way, **way** too much code. Use a debugger, or printfs right around your call to `exec` or whatever you're using to start `ls`, and check the contents of the argument array.

Comment: @Mat: I know , I've tried to debug this , a lot , but couldn't find the source of this problem . I suspect that the source is `exec` but `printf`-s didn't produce any result. Do you something wrong somewhere ? any yes ,I know this is very complex request ...

Comment: No, there's just way too much code. I can't even find any exec site. Use a debugger, break on exec and inspect  argv, there's probably a zero-length string (or unprintable garbage) in there.

Comment: Aren't you getting in a recursive loop in lines 2 (with the `&` putting the command in the background) and line three appending more data to the open file?

Comment: @Mat: You were right. thanks , it solved the problem !

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

The reason for the bug was that I sent a `char**` variable into a function that changes that 
variable , and then , I `free` that variable back in main . This is not allowed , hence I needed to send a `char***` and then everything worked out .

Thanks everybody.